# apply gridsearch CV on a scikit-learn pipeline [[feature selection] + [algorithm]] but it give the following error:

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I would like to apply gridsearch CV on a scikit-learn pipeline [[feature selection] + [algorithm]] but it give the following error, how can I correct the code?

```
 from sklearn import svm
 from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
 from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
 from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
 from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
 pipeline1 = Pipeline([ 
    ('feature_selection', SelectFromModel(svm.SVC(kernel='linear'))),
    ('filter'           , SelectKBest(k=11)),
    ('classification'   , svm.SVC(kernel='linear'))
                ])
 grid_parameters_tune = 
      [{'estimator__C': [0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0]}]
 model = GridSearchCV(pipeline1, grid_parameters_tune, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, 
                   verbose=1)
 model.fit(X, y)


ValueError: Invalid parameter estimator for estimator Pipeline(memory=None,
steps=[('feature_union', FeatureUnion(n_jobs=None,
transformer_list=[('filter', SelectKBest(k=10, score_func=<function f_classif at 0x000001ECCBB3E840>)), ('feature_selection', SelectFromModel(estimator=SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
decision_function_shape='ovr', ...r', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False))]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the error comes from the name in your `grid_parameters_tune`. You are trying to access `estimator__C`, but there are no steps names `estimator` in your pipeline. Renaming it `classification__C` should do the trick.

If you want to access to the `C` parameter from the SVC in `SelectFromModel`, you can do so with `feature_selection__estimator__C`

Below is a working example with random data. I changed some of the parameters from your original pipeline in order to save some time, do not necessarily copy it directly.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel, SelectKBest
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

X = pd.DataFrame(data=np.arange(1000).reshape(-1, 25))
y = np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, 1000//25)


pipeline1 = Pipeline(
    [
        ("feature_selection", SelectFromModel(svm.SVC(kernel="linear"))),
        ("filter", SelectKBest(k=11)),
        ("classification", svm.SVC(kernel="linear")),
    ]
)
grid_parameters_tune = [{"classification__C": [0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0,]}]
model = GridSearchCV(pipeline1, grid_parameters_tune, cv=3, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
model.fit(X, y)
```

As for the second way:

```
pipeline1 = Pipeline(
    [
        ("feature_selection", SelectFromModel(svm.SVC(kernel="linear"))),
        ("filter", SelectKBest(k=11)),
        ("classification", svm.SVC(kernel="linear")),
    ]
)
grid_parameters_tune = [{"feature_selection__estimator__C": [0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0,]}]
model = GridSearchCV(pipeline1, grid_parameters_tune, cv=3, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
model.fit(X, y)
```